# Equivalence in GraphQL with { [key: string]: string } in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, graphql

What is the equivalence in GraphQL `{ [key: string]: string }` in GraphQL in TypeScript?

```
#schema.gql
type App implements Node {
  name: String!
  tags: 'EQUIVALENCE { [key: string]: string }'
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Raw JSON is discouraged in GraphQL (which is what your `tags` field looks like), see this discussion: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/612

But, there is a way using custom scalar (https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/scalars) and typing `tags` as `JSON`. See here: https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/scalars#using-a-package

> I am copying the example here for posterity

```js
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema'
import { GraphQLJSON } from 'graphql-scalars'

const schemaString = `

scalar JSON

type Foo {
  tags: JSON
}

type Query {
  foo: Foo
}

`

const resolveFunctions = {
  JSON: GraphQLJSON
}

const jsSchema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: schemaString, resolvers: resolveFunctions })
```

If you can, I would suggest choosing something like this:

```
#schema.gql
type App implements Node {
  name: String!
  tags: [ { name: String!, value: String! }! ]!
}
```